# Looping through a list of webpages with rvest follow_link

Tags: r, web-scraping, lapply, rvest

I'm trying to webscrape the government release calendar: https://www.gov.uk/government/statistics and use the rvest follow_link functionality to go to each publication link and scrape text from the next page. I have this working for each single page of results (40 publications are displayed per page), but can't get a loop to work so that I can run the code over all publications listed.

This is the code I run first to get the list of publications (just from the first 10 pages of results):

```
#Loading the rvest package
library('rvest')
library('dplyr')
library('tm')

#######PUBLISHED RELEASES################

###function to add number after 'page=' in url to loop over all pages of published releases results (only 40 publications per page)
###check the site and see how many pages you want to scrape, to cover months of interest
##titles of publications - creates a list
publishedtitles <- lapply(paste0('https://www.gov.uk/government/statistics?page=', 1:10),
                 function(url_base){
                   url_base %>% read_html() %>% 
                     html_nodes('h3 a') %>% 
                     html_text()
                 })


##Dates of publications
publisheddates <- lapply(paste0('https://www.gov.uk/government/statistics?page=', 1:10),
                 function(url_base){
                   url_base %>% read_html() %>% 
                     html_nodes('.public_timestamp') %>% 
                     html_text()
                 })
##Organisations
publishedorgs <- lapply(paste0('https://www.gov.uk/government/statistics?page=', 1:10),
                function(url_base){
                  url_base %>% read_html() %>% 
                    html_nodes('.organisations') %>% 
                    html_text()
                })
##Links to publications
publishedpartial_links <- lapply(paste0('https://www.gov.uk/government/statistics?page=', 1:10),
               function(url_base){
                 url_base %>% read_html() %>% 
                   html_nodes('h3 a') %>% 
                   html_attr('href') 
               })

#Check all lists are the same length - if not, have to deal with missings before next step
# length(publishedtitles)
# length(publisheddates)
# length(publishedorgs)
# length(publishedpartial_links)
#str(publishedorgs)

#Combining all the lists to form a data frame
published <-data.frame(Title = unlist(publishedtitles), Date = unlist(publisheddates), Organisation = unlist(publishedorgs), PartLinks = unlist(publishedpartial_links))

#adding prefix to partial links, to turn into full URLs
published$Links = paste("https://www.gov.uk", published$PartLinks, sep="")
#Drop partial links column
keeps <- c("Title", "Date", "Organisation", "Links")
published <- published[keeps]
```

Then I want to run something like the below, but over all pages of results. I've ran this code manually changing the parameters for each page, so know it works.

```
session1 <- html_session("https://www.gov.uk/government/statistics?page=1")
list1 <- list()
for(i in published$Title[1:40]){
  nextpage1 <- session1 %>% follow_link(i) %>% read_html()
  list1[[i]]<- nextpage1 %>%
    html_nodes(".grid-row") %>% html_text()
  df1 <- data.frame(text=list1)
  df1 <-as.data.frame(t(df1))
}
```

So the above would need to change page=1 in the html_session, and also the publication$Title[1:40] - I'm struggling with creating a function or loop that includes both variables.

I think I should be able to do this using lapply:

```
df <- lapply(paste0('https://www.gov.uk/government/statistics?page=', 1:10),
                          function(url_base){
                              for(i in published$Title[1:40]){
                                nextpage1 <- url_base %>% follow_link(i) %>% read_html()
                                list1[[i]]<- nextpage1 %>%
                                  html_nodes(".grid-row") %>% html_text()
                              }
                          }
)
```

But I get the error

```
Error in follow_link(., i) : is.session(x) is not TRUE
```

I've also tried other methods of looping and turning it into a function but didn't want to make this post too long!

**Thanks in advance for any suggestions and guidance :)**

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have just need to start a session inside the `lapply` function.  In the last chunk of code, `url_base` is simply a text string that gives the base URL.  Would something like this work:

```
df <- lapply(paste0('https://www.gov.uk/government/statistics?page=', 1:10),
                        function(url_base){
                            for(i in published$Title[1:40]){
                                tmpSession <- html_session(url_base)
                                nextpage1 <- tmpSession %>% follow_link(i) %>% read_html()
                                list1[[i]]<- nextpage1 %>%
                                html_nodes(".grid-row") %>% html_text()
                            }
                        }
)
```

To change the `published$Title[1:40]` for each iteraction of the `lapply` function, you could make an object that holds the lower and upper bounds of the indices:

```
lowers <- cumsum(c(1, rep(40, 9)))
uppers <- cumsum(rep(40, 10))
```

Then, you could include those in the call to `lapply`

```
df <- lapply(1:10, function(j){
    url_base <- paste0('https://www.gov.uk/government/statistics?page=', j)
    for(i in published$Title[lowers[j]:uppers[j]]){
        tmpSession <- html_session(url_base)
        nextpage1 <- tmpSession %>% follow_link(i) %>% read_html()
        list1[[i]]<- nextpage1 %>%
        html_nodes(".grid-row") %>% html_text()
    }
}
)
```

Not sure if this is what you want or not, I might have misunderstood the things that are supposed to be changing.

Comment: The idea of using tmpSession (from the first bit of code) is helpful but I'm still getting errors as once it's scraped the links from the first page https://www.gov.uk/government/statistics?page=1 it then tries to look for those same links again on page 2. Instead, I need it to look for the titles within published$Title[41:80]. Is there a way to functionalise this part rather than having to write out the same code for each list of 40 titles/links?